# Npm Install is Failing

Tags: vue.js

When I call `npm install`, these errors are thrown:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: taxihub-admin@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^7.32.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^6.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

OS: Ubuntu

Versions:
npm: '9.6.3',
node: '18.15.0',

Here is the package.json file, for the dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "echarts": "^4.8.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "firebase": "^7.16.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "v-calendar": "^1.0.8",
    "v2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-echarts": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue-flag-icon": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-fontawesome-icon": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-good-table": "^2.19.5",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.18.2",
    "vue-instantsearch": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-jstree": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-simple-calendar": "^4.4.0",
    "vue-slider-component": "^3.2.2",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-tour": "^1.5.0",
    "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.5.1",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.0",
    "vuejs-smart-table": "0.0.5",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
```

Basically I have a js vuejs app, which I've been trying to debug since yesterday, but every time I try to install the dependencies I get an error with 'eslint', I've had to change the version of npm and node but without success, I don't know what the error is related to.

Comment: Read the error. It offers some options what you can do.

Comment: The error explains what's wrong. You need eslint-plugin-vue 7 in order for it to be compatible with eslint 7. It's unknown how you ended up with incompatible set of deps, probably there's something more

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by a `dependency conflict` between the `eslint` package and the `eslint-plugin-vue` package.

The `eslint-plugin-vue` package requires a version of eslint that is either `5.x` or `6.x`, while your project has eslint version `7.32.0` installed. This means that the `eslint-plugin-vue` package cannot be installed because it has a `peer dependency` conflict with eslint.

To resolve this issue, you can either downgrade the version of eslint to `5.x or 6.x`, or upgrade `eslint-plugin-vue` to a version that supports eslint version `7.x.`